# Write a SQL query to display all employee names and salary whose salary is greater than minimum salary of the company and job title starts with ‘M’?

Tags: mysql

I have to display the names of employees,salary and job where salary must be greater that minimum salary in table and his/her job should be starting with letter 'M'.
i tried this

```
select ename,sal,job from emp where sal>min(sal) and job like "M%";
```

but it says

```
Invalid use of group function.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inner Query for minimum salary.

```
 SELECT ename, sal, job 
 from emp 
 where sal > (SELECT min(sal) from emp)) //innerQuery
 and job like "M%"
```

Comment: @ramkishore just curious, why did you accept this late and typographically incorrect answer over the earlier, and typographically correct one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT ename, sal, job from emp where sal > (SELECT min(`sal`) from emp) and job like "M%"
```